# Google chrome update error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, google-chrome, dependencies

I wanted to update my Google Chrome and I tried various methods which I found on the internet. But nothing worked and I got the following error:

```
Error: Opening the cache(E:Malformed entry 1 in the list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list(URI), E:The list of sources could not be read.)
```

[image: error output]

This usually means that the installed packages have unmet dependencies.

I am not sure if I ask properly. Can you help me solve this issue?

Comment: Once installed with the provided .deb, Google Chrome adds its own repository and from then on it's updated automatically along with all the other updates. In a nutshell, to have Google Chrome updated all you need to do is keep your system updated.

Comment: Thanks. I think I fixed the error now. How can I isntall .deb?

Comment: If you already have Chrome installed -and- the correct repository you don't need anything else. Check Software&Updates > Other software. The correct repo is http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ and nothing else, no duplicates, etc.

Comment: Yes, it was. Thanks a lot!